# git push force to Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, git

I am writing a project on Overleaf and have a local copy via git.
I did some local changes and now my local version is out of sync with the Overleaf one.
I tried to `git push --force` my local changes (since I want to rewrite the Overleaf repo), but I get a permission error.
Anyone knows how I can enable `git push --force` on Overleaf?

Comment: Hmmm, this is probably best asked to Overleaf's tech support...

Comment: @Rmano I tried that. But didn't get a reply :(

Comment: this is really off topic here, but just checking, you do have the pro version of overleaf? The github linkage is not available to the free version as far as I know.

Comment: @becko I've just written back to you via email, sorry it wasn't sooner. We've had a very busy day on Overleaf support today.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It's not linked to Github. I am just using a local git repo mirroring the Overleaf repo.

Comment: @PaulGessler Yes, thanks. Do you want to post an answer? Can be useful to other users.

Comment: You cannot `force` the `push` action. The correct way is (1) to do `git pull` and then (2) to do `git push`. Between (1) and (2), you can choose which version to keep (your version, the Overleaf version or a merge between the two versions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case someone else has the same question, I got the following answer from Overleaf support.

TLDR; It's not possible to force push to Overleaf.

> Hi there,
>
> Thanks for getting in touch about this. Force pushing to an Overleaf
> remote isn't possible at the moment, sorry for the limitation here.
> Usually force pushing is not necessary: if there is a merge conflict,
> it can be resolved in the usual way.
>
> If you really do need to force push, it would be good to understand
> more about the situation you're in so we can advise how to resolve
> this. One workaround would be to re-apply your changes over the top of
> the current Overleaf remote head.
>
> The process would be similar to steps 5-8 here:
> https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Using_Git_and_GitHub#Creating_an_Overleaf_project_from_an_existing_Git_repository
> but would need to be adapted to your situation. Those directions are
> for a new Overleaf project based on some existing git repository that
> has a differing history to Overleaf's. But the steps would be similar
> to re-apply your changes from Overleaf's current state.
>
> If you could explain more about the changes you need to commit, and
> the current state of the Overleaf project (ideally with an example
> project), we might be able to provide more specific advice on how to
> work around this.
>
> Thanks,
>
> Paul

Comment: So what was your specific case that you needed a force push?

Comment: I did a lot of modifications locally, while also doing some accidental modifications on the overleaf web. I want to overwrite the overleaf version with my local changes. My collaborators are aware of I'm doing, so the simplest solution would be to force push the changes and that's it!

Comment: I ended up in a similar situation after attempting to clean up git history.